# Status 404 when trying to redirect a page using "redirect:" prefix when returning a ModelAndView

Tags: spring-mvc, redirect, post-redirect-get, modelandview

I'm trying to redirect my request after a success login, 2 pages are involved, commonly **login** and **loginsuccess**

here is the Controller class for Login mapping

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("userObj")
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView initLoginView(ModelAndView mv) {

    mv.addObject("userObj", new User());
    mv.setViewName("user/login");

    return mv;
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ModelAndView loginUser(ModelAndView mv, @ModelAttribute("userObj") User user, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {

    System.out.println(user.getUserName());
    System.out.println(user.getPassword());

    mv.addObject("userObj", user);
    mv.setViewName("redirect:/user/loginSuccess");

    return mv;
  }
}
```

I'm getting a **404, resource not found** error, so I suspect that my returned ModelAndView object from the POST method is the culprit, so I changed the returned value **into**

```
mv.setViewName("user/loginSuccess");
return mv;
```

**from**

```
mv.setViewName("redirect:/user/loginSuccess");
return mv;
```

and is successfully loads the page, I'm trying to achieve *"post/redirect/get design pattern"* that avoids duplicate form submission, I'm seeing alot of examples around that uses **redirect:** 
in a **ModelAndView object**, but non of them I saw a 404 exception issue. any help out there please. And Thanks in advance.

**EDITED**: when I make the return statement like this **mv.setViewName("user/loginSuccess");**
I get this warning when I **refresh** the **loginSucsess page**

[image: duplicate form submission]

Answer (score 0):

I just manage to dig some resources around the web and fortunately the server throws me a **"WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI** that made me realize to do this kind of approach

**NOTE: instead of a "Login" feature I decided to solve my problem with a "Register" feature** ,Its still the same feature that deals with **POST** method and I just found some good resource about **Spring Security** when it comes to creating a Login feature

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("userObj")
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

@Resource(name = "userManager")
private UserManager userManager;

@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView setUpRegisterView(ModelAndView mv) {

    mv.addObject("userObj", new User());
    mv.setViewName("user/register");

    return mv;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView registerUser(ModelAndView mv, @ModelAttribute("userObj") User user, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes ra) {

    userManager.saveUser(user);

    mv = new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/user/registerSuccess", true));
    ra.addFlashAttribute(user);

    return mv;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/registerSuccess", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView registerSuccess(ModelAndView mv) {

    mv.setViewName("user/registerSuccess");
    return mv;
 }
}
```

Using **RedirectView** class and adding another handler method to map the redirecting view, I manage to overcome the duplicate-form-submision problem, refreshing the "**registerSuccess**" page and monitoring my database, no duplicate of data is occuring.

Its just weird that I cant find any example using **RedirectView** class saying that **another handler method is needed to map the redirect request**

Answer (score 0):

My 404 was caused by the fact that when you return a view of "/myPage.jsp", you do

```
return "/myPage";
```

but when you redirect to it, you do

`return "redirect:/myPage`.**jsp**`"`;